# Calculate number of mondays in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Can you please tell me how to count the number of Mondays in a column with dates in a Google spreadsheet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `FILTER()` function.

```
=COUNT(FILTER(A2:A7,WEEKDAY(A2:A7)=2))
```

Or direct day name.

```
=COUNT(FILTER(A2:A7,TEXT(A2:A7,"dddd")="Monday"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your field is date format, then run this formula:
A1 to A24 is your cells for calculation.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A1:A24)=2))
```

Comment: no need for `--` this: `=SUMPRODUCT(WEEKDAY(A1:A24)=2)` works too

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with a formula like this:

```
=--(WEEKDAY(A1)=2)
```

where `A1` is the date in your example.

That new column will contain a `1` for mondays, and `0` for anything else. From there you can just sum the new column to get the # of mondays.